# ARMv8 illegal instruction

Tags: c, arm, armv8, illegal-instruction

I have written the following assembly for ARMv8:

```
        .text
        .align  4
        .global permute
        .type   permute, %function
permute:
        ld2 {v0.2d - v1.2d}, [x0], #32
        ld2 {v2.2d - v3.2d}, [x0], #32
        ld2 {v4.2d - v5.2d}, [x0], #32
        ld2 {v6.2d - v7.2d}, [x0]  
        zip1 v8.2d, v0.2d, v4.2d
        st1 {v0.2d - v3.2d}, [x1], #64
        st1 {v4.2d - v7.2d}, [x1]
```

The function `permute` is called from a regular C program with two byte pointers of length 128 as inputs. This compiles fine, but when I run it I get `Illegal instruction`. If I comment out the `zip1` instruction, it also runs fine.

Any tips on what might be wrong, and how to debug `Illegal instruction` in general?

Comment: Does any ARM documentation say anything about a `zip1` instruction?

Comment: @klutt. http://115.28.165.193/down/arm/arch/ARM_v8_Instruction_Set_Architecture_%28Overview%29.pdf

Comment: why do not you use C with vector intrinsics? They are well defined in the CMSIS

Comment: See page 1636 of this document: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0801g/DUI0801G_armasm_user_guide.pdf.

Comment: @SergioFormiggini I've read the documentation, but I still don't understand why it gives `Illegal instruction`.

Comment: Okay, it seems that adding `ret` in the end of the function fixes things

Comment: :) really you forgot to return from the routine?

Comment: @MartinLauridsen Why did it work without the `zip1`, then?

Comment: I think it worked 'cause you were "lucky" ... ;) 

Honestly, I thought it was obvious the ret in the end ...